# How to sketch the region that a section is mapped onto it under $w=z^3$

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's an excercise in "complex variables and applications 8th edition" chapter two page 44 question 3:
It says sketch the region that the section $r\le1$ , $0\le \theta \le \pi/4$ with the map $w=z^2$ , $w=z^3$, $w=x^4$ is mapped onto it. (Excuse my possible translation mistakes.)

So under $w=z^2$ we have $w(z)=r^2e^{2\theta i}$ and $0 \le r^2 \le 1$ and $0 \le2\theta \le \pi/2$
This is clearly the quarter of a circle with radius 1 and centre 0 in the upper half plane.
I don't know how to sketch the other two sections.

With $w=z^3$ we have section $0 \le r^3 \le 1$ and $0 \le Arg w \le 3\pi/4$ how do I sketch this??

Answer (score 1):

One general approach, for mapping $z^n$, for $z \in \Bbb{C_{\neq 0}}$ is to map by **rays**.  That is for $z = re^{i\theta}$, $z^n = r^n e^{in\theta}.$  Two things are happening here:

- Each element on the ray, where arg$(z) = \theta$ is mapped to the ray corresponding to arg$(z^n) = n\theta$.
- Absolute value (i.e. the *norm*) of $z^n$ (i.e. the distance of $z^n$ to the origin) will be less than $z$, equal to $z$ or greater than $z$, depending on whether the abolute value of $z$ is less than $1$, equal to $1$, or greater than $1$.  Here, I am assuming that $n \in \Bbb{R_{>1}}.$

Answer (score 0):

It's all much the same in this case: $z^3$ produces a sector of radius $1$ with $0\le\theta\le3\pi/4$ and $z^4$ produces the upper half-disc. It is convenient that the radius is $1$, otherwise the sector size would change; points with absolute value less than $1$ move closer under any power map, points with absolute value greater than $1$ move farther away.

Comment: You may wish to expand your answer, re $r \leq 1.$